# Nodejs Numtel Mysql over a SSH connection

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, meteor, ssh

I'm having a problem with using the numtel meteor package to send and receive MySql information over a network (The database being located on a server). Currently, it is able to push information from the db to the screen using his package, but the problem occurs after the first load. On the first load, it is able to retrieve information from the database, and display that to the screen, but anything after that, it seems that the triggers are broken, but only somewhat. I am able to send information to the server, but it seems to fail on dynamic retrieval. Information gets sent to the server just fine, but the information is then not retrieved and displayed back onto the screen. It also only breaks once as a I add the tunneling code. It previous worked and got the updates when using a database on the same machine.

```
messages = new MysqlSubscription('getMessages');

messages.addEventListener('update', function(diff, data) {
    console.log("Event listener");
});

if (Meteor.isClient) {
Template.messageHistory.helpers({
    messages: function () {
      return messages.reactive(); 
    }
  });
} 
if (Meteor.isServer) {

  var Tunnel = Meteor.npmRequire('tunnel-ssh');    
  var config = {
        host: "ourhost",
        username: "uname",
        password: "password",
        port:22,
        dstPort:3306,
        srcPort:3307,
      };

  Tunnel.tunnel(config, function(err) { (err == null) ? console.log(config) : console.log(err) })

  var liveDb = new LiveMysql({
                   host:"localhost",
                   port:3307,
                   database: "db",
                   user: "root",
                   password: "password"
               });

 Meteor.publish('getMessages', function() {
    return liveDb.select(
      'SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY Timestamp', 
      [ { table: 'messages' } ]
    );
  });
}
```

Comment: Ever get anywhere with this? Any chance the SSH tunnel needs a keep-alive or something?

Comment: O ya sorry i forgot to update it, my problem was in my my.cnf file for mysql. I had server-id and it needed to be server_id

Answer (score 0):

My problem was in my my.cnf file for mysql. I had server-id and it needed to be server_id